# Other variable value null when change new one

Tags: php, html

I am making admin panel for own site.

I have five input fields they all goes with post method into the variable and these variables call into the image src.

Here is [Demo](http://musicjee.com/admin-panal/new%20%203.php)

If all input fields fill with image links then work fine after that if l change only one link so than other pictures lost.

PHP & HTML

```
<form action="" method="post">

<input type="url" name="img1"/>
<input type="url" name="img2"/>

</form>

<?php
       if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

       $img1=$_POST['img-one'];

       $img2=$_POST['img-two'];

       ?>

        <div><img id="admin-image-pack-2" alt="null" src="<?php echo $img1; ?>"/><img id="admin-image-pack-2" alt="null" src="<?php echo $img2; ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your post `$_POST['img-one']` is not `null` before you assign it to the variable.
This way if you only update the second value for example you won't lose the first one.
Do the same with all your Posts.

Example:

```
if (!empty($_POST['img-one']))
{  
    $img1=$_POST['img-one'];  
}
```

Comment: Please if you provide me code maybe it's clear to understand for me.

Comment: But same happened again.why it's not working.If super global variable not empty so then set vale to variable it's true but else.Image again lost.